# Using npm with a java project?

Tags: java, npm, ant

I wanted to use npm scripts to automate some things with a java application I am working on.

I've made a start script that runs `ant` changes to the `dist/` folder and runs three instances of the app with the `concurrently`

my script looks as follows:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ant && cd dist/ && concurrently \"java -jar ChatApplication-Server.jar Mode=Client\" \"java -jar ChatApplication-Server.jar Mode=Client\" \"java -jar ChatApplication-Server.jar Mode=Server\"", 
},
```

It somehow seems wrong to use npm to work with a java application? Can I achieve what I am trying to do with just using ant alone somehow?

Comment: Why is it wrong? It is just a tool.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Well it does incur yet another dependency, entirely gratuitously.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I don't know if it is wrong. I am just often curious if I am using the right tool for a specific job.

Comment: Why are you using `npm` for this instead of using Ant? Won't something like `<parallel>` do this? (I've forgotten about ant almost entirely :/

Comment: It may or may not make sense depending on project needs.  I've done a very large J2EE project that used both ant and npm because it made sense.  It was a monolithic application where the front-end was coupled to the back-end and we needed to overhaul the front-end and wanted to use browserify to build it.  For the deploy scripts we had ant calling npm to build front-end and deploy.  It depend entirely on your project and we can't tell you flat out if a toolchain is correct for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

NPM is a javascript package manager, so it is a tool built with javascript in mind.

Instead of using NPM, you should use a java specialised tool like maven or gradle.

Each tool has it's use. You don't hammer a nail with a screwdriver.

Comment: Ant *is* one such tool for Java. Except, arguably, anywhere between 1-3 generations behind Maven and Gradle.